# How to find sum in a list using classes

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, sum

It can be done in a much easier method using functions but since I'm practicing OOP, I wanted to try coding this problem using classes.

```
class Numbers:
    def __init__(self):
       self.__sum=0
    def addNumber(self, number):
       self.__sum += number
    def currentSum(self):
       return self.__sum

numbers = Numbers()
a = ['3 2', '1 2']
for n in a:
    for i in n.split():
        numbers.addNumber(int(i))
        print(numbers.currentSum())
```

However, the output produced was this:

```
3
5
6
8
```

rather than

```
5
3
```

Comment: If you want to de facto practice OO you might want to do so using a more properly OO language such as Java or C++.

Comment: Why should `5 3` be printed? You are printing the sum everytime you add a number... Maybe you meant to unindent the print line?

Comment: @cricket_007 I want to print the sum of values shown for each element in list 'a' `3+2 = 5` and `1+2=3` instead of iterating all the integers in all the elements together.

Comment: I see. The answers address that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the class instance inside the first loop.  And print outside the second loop.

```
class Numbers:
    def __init__(self):
       self.__sum=0
    def addNumber(self, number):
       self.__sum += number
    def currentSum(self):
       return self.__sum

a = ['3 2', '1 2']
for n in a:
  numbers = Numbers()
  for i in n.split():
      numbers.addNumber(int(i))
  print(numbers.currentSum())
```

Comment: you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

Two things;

- You need to reset the sum for each string, otherwise you'll get 5 8.
- You'll want to print the result once you looped through all numbers in a string, not *while* looping. Fix this by unintenting the print.

```
a = ['3 2', '1 2']
for n in a:
    numbers = Numbers()               <-- reset sum per string
    for i in n.split():
        numbers.addNumber(int(i))
    print(numbers.currentSum())       <-- do this _after_ the loop

# 5
# 3
```